# Seasonal ARIMA model problem with (1,0,1) x (1,0,1) [4]

Tags: r, time-series

There are certain rules as to how much to difference the seasonal and non-seasonal components in seasonal ARIMA as in [here](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/seasarim.htm).

However, I don't see why the following code results in an error:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(0)
model <- Arima(ts(rnorm(100),freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1),
             fixed=c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))
```

as follows:

```
Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
  wrong length for 'fixed'
```

when differencing the seasonal component avoids the error:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(0)
model <- Arima(ts(rnorm(100),freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,1,1),
             fixed=c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ARIMA model without seasonal differencing includes a constant by default, which also needs to be included in the vector of `fixed` coefficients.

You can remove the constant by setting `include.mean=FALSE`.

```r
library(forecast)
set.seed(0)
model <- Arima(ts(rnorm(100),freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1), 
               include.mean = FALSE,
               fixed=c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))
model
#> Series: ts(rnorm(100), freq = 4) 
#> ARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,1)[4] with zero mean 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  ar1   ma1  sar1  sma1  
#>  0.5  -0.4   0.3  -0.2  
#> 
#> sigma^2 = 0.7799:  log likelihood = -129.5
#> AIC=261   AICc=261.04   BIC=263.61
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>